# Error instantiating servlet class [org.ran.FristServlet]

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Hi writing a code using apache Tomcat i'm keep getting the above. I have checked the Web.xml path

[image]

and the content of the web.xml i didn't find any mistake

[image]

below is my code and error message

index.jsp

[image]

FirstServlet

```
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        rd.forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String uid = req.getParameter("uid");
        int ph = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("ph"));

        HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        if (uid != null && ph < 0) {

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306?user=root&password=Eagle&useSSL=false");

                String sql = "select invno,phone from invnt.allinvoice where invno=? and phone=? ";
                pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstmt.setString(1, uid);
                pstmt.setInt(2, ph);
                rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

                String nid="";
                int nph=0;

                while (rs.next()) {
                    nid=rs.getString(1);
                    nph=rs.getInt(2);
                }
                if(uid==nid && ph==nph) {
                    RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
                    rd.forward(req, resp);
                }else{
                    RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
                    rd.forward(req, resp);
                }

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            rd.forward(req, resp);
        }
    }
```

error log

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [org.ran.FristServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ran.FristServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1363)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61
```

Comment: I spotted a space `<servlet-name> FirstServlet` and it is First not Frist?

Comment: @JoopEggen removed the space but same error and its FirstServlet

Comment: Ok i just renamed the servlet from frist to first and changed it every where but still its showing like that i didt noticed it

Comment: Compiling, creating the .war deploying. It seems as if that pipeline goes wrong somewhere. Maybe someone else experiences similar. You might stop tomcat, clean all possible directories and retry.

Answer (score 0):

First remove all servlet and its servletmapping tags from your web.xml because 
you can simply use annotations instead of writing that deployment descriptor code.
Also your project structure is disturbed you should
put your servlet in src/main/java and try running it.

Also annotate your class like below.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/fs", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

Comment: Sometimes on creating of filters or servlets, the class file is not generated in build folder in eclipse.Clean the application and build it once, a .class file is generated in that above said path. This removes class not found error in some cases. Also you can try deleting your .metadata hidden folder in eclipse workspace